# What does pointer variable store?

Tags: c, pointers

I typed in this code:

```
char *a;
char b = 'd';
a = b;
printf("%c", a);
```

Output - 'd'.

My query is that since `a` is pointer variable, it is supposed to store address. Why in this case is it storing character value?

Comment: You just changed the pointers value to the ascii value of a.

Comment: Your compiler *should* have complained about the assignment at the very least; assigning an integer value to a pointer object is a *constraint violation*.  Note that gcc also complains about the `printf` statement, since the type of `a` (`char *`) is not what the `%c` conversion specifier expects (`char`).

Comment: No, there are no warnings or errors in my gnu gcc compiler

Comment: One more question . Is this statement correct "Only an address of a variable can be stored in a pointer variable" ? I read it in my book.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> since `a` is pointer variable, it is supposed to store address

A pointer variable can store numeric values, too. On most systems a pointer variable could store an `int`, although there is no explicit guarantee of this. However, a pointer variable is capable of storing a value of type `char` on all systems.

> then why in this case is it storing character value?

Because you told it to do so. Storing a value in a pointer does not make that value an address.

**Note:** your code has undefined behavior. The reason the code produces the output that you expect is that a pointer representation on your system happens to be compatible with that of an `int`, which is what `%c` expects.

Comment: Nice answer... The only thing missing is that the address of `b` is written as `&b` (e.g. "perhaps you meant to write `a = &b;`?"...). Also, since the OP is confused about this whichever resource he's using to learn obviously isn't working, and he should probably try K&R2e...

Comment: Correction: If you're going to bring up that, you might also want to bring up `%p`... So much to learn, so little book...

Comment: I am using ANSI C by E Balaguruswamy . And I meant to write b , not &b . I know difference between both.

Comment: One more question . Is this statement correct "Only an address of a variable can be stored in a pointer variable" ? I read it in my book.

Comment: @AkhilRaj The book oversimplifies things a bit, because pointers can hold numeric values as well. Starting with C99 there are even special types available for converting pointers to/from integral types in a standard-compliant way - namely, `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`. However, since it is exceptionally rare that one would need this sort of functionality, I wouldn't blame authors of the book for not mentioning this obscure piece of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

pointer is a variable which stores the address of the another variable.but here you wrote a=b which means your are providing the character d to which will the a store.this is because the pointer is also a variable.it is also having its own address space.while we provide the address of the another variable the pointer stores that address that means pointer have the storing capacity. but in this program you cant dereference the pointer.you will get segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Talking in reference with C, a pointer variable stores the address of the variable it is pointing to. **In C we cannot use it like any other ordinary variable to store other type of data.** Moreover, the datatype of the pointer variable is the variable pointing to or if we declare it as void we need to cast it in as per necessity(i.e. the data type of pointing variable).

Talking in reference to your query, since you have already declared it as "pointer variable"  so the function of "printf" is to print the data the pointer variable is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

Although your code output seems to be working based on the reasons that [@dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight) told, that is not a correct practice to assign a `char` to a `char*`. The compiler (GCC 4.8.4) warning also is helpful to understand the issue:

```
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  a = b;
    ^
```

When you assign an `int` to a `int*` the compiler prints such warning. It also applies to `char` and `char*` in the same way because a `char` is a form of `int` in C.